# Is sum of the reciprocal of any subsequence of natural number divergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let, $\{a_n\}$ be any subsequence of natural numbers.

Then, is $\sum\frac{1}{a_n}$ always divergent?

Comment: This is almost like asking if there are any series that converge...

Answer (score 1):

No. Consider the subsequence defined by the powers of two: $\{2,4,8,16,32,64,...\}$. This results in the summation

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} = \frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{4} +\frac{1}{8} +\frac{1}{16} +\frac{1}{32} + ...$$

We note that this is an infinite geometric series of ratio $1/2$. Thus, from the formula for the summation of such a series, it can be shown that this summation converges to $1$.

Truly many such series exist; this is just one such example.

Answer (score 1):

No. It is easy to produce a counter example

Let $a_n=n^2$. So it is the sequence of square numbers 1, 4, 9 ,16 ,..

Then it is [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem) that:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^p}:\left\{\begin{matrix}
\mathrm{converges} &,p>1 \\ 
\mathrm{diverges} &,p\leq1 
\end{matrix}\right.$

Answer (score 1):

No. Even though $\sum 1/n$ diverges, 
if you discard all the terms whose denominator involves the digit $9$, the series would become convergent, and the sum would be less than $80$.

Comment: Several correct answers to this question, but this is the only cute answer (so far).

Answer (score 0):

Let $n$ be any natural number greater than $1$,

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n^k}=\frac{1}{1-\frac1n}=\frac{n}{n-1}$$

is a geometric series that converges.